# grouping of order line items for orders

Tags: sql

Hi i have a table with orders and order iD as primary key and another table order line itme with line item id and primary key, which alos had order id from order table, i would like to pull the list of orders whrere orders are having more than one line item

example:

```
Orders  
123 
456 
789
```

order line items

```
Line item ID    Order ID
abc 123
qwe 456
zxc 789
edc 123
wsx 456
tio 123
zxc 456
```

Result

```
Order ID    Count of Line Item ID 
123             2
456             3
```

Comment: need the line items to be displayed as well with count

Comment: Hi.  Please format your sample data such that it is readable and has proper columns.

Answer (score 0):

```
select orderid, count(*)
from orders
group by orderid
```

Comment: apologies I was looking at the wrong table.  The answer from scaisEdge looks like it will do what you need.

Answer (score 0):

You can use group by for aggregation and having for filter the order_id with more than 1

```
select order_id, count(*) 
from order_line_table
group by order_id 
having count(*) >1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `HAVING`:

```
SELECT order_id, COUNT(order_id) count FROM line_items GROUP BY order_id HAVING count > 1
```